# Help Wordpress contact form 7 issue with input widths on radio buttons?

Tags: wordpress, forms, contacts

Hi all fellow wordpressers

I'd like to customize the width of the radio buttons on contact form 7. 
Is there a way to tell the radio buttons to be a different width to the input fields in the css.

When I put a width on the input fields I don't want this to apply to the radio buttons.

Thanks for all your help

Regards 
judi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a class to the radio button in your form template on the settings page. Then open the Contact Form 7's CSS stylesheet file, possibly located at:

```
/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/stylesheet.css
```

and setup css rules for the input with class "radio":

```
input.my_radio {
width: 140px;
}
```

To assign a class to radio input or to checkbox input use:

```
[radio your-eyes-color class:my_radio "brown" "green" "blue"]
```

Above code will generate the markup:

```
<input type="radio" name="your-eyes-color" class="my_radio" value="brown" /> brown
<input type="radio" name="your-eyes-color" class="my_radio" value="green" /> green
<input type="radio" name="your-eyes-color" class="my_radio" value="blue" /> blue
```

Learn more at [Contact Form 7 website](http://contactform7.com/2009/11/20/checkboxes-radio-buttons-and-menus/).
Good luck!